# Excel Error | Copy Data from multiple excel to one workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have a file that copy data range from one excel to the main file until it finish copying all excel file in a folder. But the problem is it crashes. It close the file entirely. Below is the formula

```
Sub kopy()


Dim path As String

path = "\\vtr-dept\WFM\CWFT\VTO Hours\"
Dim myfile As String

myfile = Dir("\\vtr-dept\WFM\CWFT\VTO Hours\")
Do While Len(myfile) > 0


    Workbooks.Open (path & myfile)

    'lookup file name

    Range("A11").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=MID(CELL(""filename""),SEARCH(""["",CELL(""filename""))+1, SEARCH(""]"",CELL(""filename""))-SEARCH(""["",CELL(""filename""))-1)"
    Range("A11").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("B11").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Range("A31").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("A11").Select

    Range("A11:J31").Copy


    Windows("MainFile.xlsm").Activate
    Range("A1").Select
    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    Windows(myfile).Activate
    Range("A11:A31").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

   ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False


myfile = Dir

Loop
  MsgBox "Tapos na po. Mabuhay ang kilusan"
Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the error you get, and on which line does it occur?

Comment: Set a breakpoint and step debug code. On which line does it crash?

Comment: path and myfile are the exact same thing check the source of this code and I'm sure that is not what was there.--it also may be a good idea to have the complete folder location.

Comment: it does not provide any line error, it only automatically close the excel files

Answer (score 0):

You can easily merge all Excel files in a folder into one Master file.

```
Sub Basic_Example_1()
    Dim MyPath As String, FilesInPath As String
    Dim MyFiles() As String
    Dim SourceRcount As Long, Fnum As Long
    Dim mybook As Workbook, BaseWks As Worksheet
    Dim sourceRange As Range, destrange As Range
    Dim rnum As Long, CalcMode As Long

    'Fill in the path\folder where the files are
    MyPath = "C:\Users\Ron\test"

    'Add a slash at the end if the user forget it
    If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        MyPath = MyPath & "\"
    End If

    'If there are no Excel files in the folder exit the sub
    FilesInPath = Dir(MyPath & "*.xl*")
    If FilesInPath = "" Then
        MsgBox "No files found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Fill the array(myFiles)with the list of Excel files in the folder
    Fnum = 0
    Do While FilesInPath <> ""
        Fnum = Fnum + 1
        ReDim Preserve MyFiles(1 To Fnum)
        MyFiles(Fnum) = FilesInPath
        FilesInPath = Dir()
    Loop

    'Change ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'Add a new workbook with one sheet
    Set BaseWks = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)
    rnum = 1

    'Loop through all files in the array(myFiles)
    If Fnum > 0 Then
        For Fnum = LBound(MyFiles) To UBound(MyFiles)
            Set mybook = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFiles(Fnum))
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not mybook Is Nothing Then

                On Error Resume Next

                With mybook.Worksheets(1)
                    Set sourceRange = .Range("A1:C1")
                End With

                If Err.Number > 0 Then
                    Err.Clear
                    Set sourceRange = Nothing
                Else
                    'if SourceRange use all columns then skip this file
                    If sourceRange.Columns.Count >= BaseWks.Columns.Count Then
                        Set sourceRange = Nothing
                    End If
                End If
                On Error GoTo 0

                If Not sourceRange Is Nothing Then

                    SourceRcount = sourceRange.Rows.Count

                    If rnum + SourceRcount >= BaseWks.Rows.Count Then
                        MsgBox "Sorry there are not enough rows in the sheet"
                        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
                        mybook.Close savechanges:=False
                        GoTo ExitTheSub
                    Else

                        'Copy the file name in column A
                        With sourceRange
                            BaseWks.cells(rnum, "A"). _
                                    Resize(.Rows.Count).Value = MyFiles(Fnum)
                        End With

                        'Set the destrange
                        Set destrange = BaseWks.Range("B" & rnum)

                        'we copy the values from the sourceRange to the destrange
                        With sourceRange
                            Set destrange = destrange. _
                                            Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)
                        End With
                        destrange.Value = sourceRange.Value

                        rnum = rnum + SourceRcount
                    End If
                End If
                mybook.Close savechanges:=False
            End If

        Next Fnum
        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
    End If

ExitTheSub:
    'Restore ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With
End Sub

Function RDB_Last(choice As Integer, rng As Range)
'Ron de Bruin, 5 May 2008
' 1 = last row
' 2 = last column
' 3 = last cell
    Dim lrw As Long
    Dim lcol As Integer

    Select Case choice

    Case 1:
        On Error Resume Next
        RDB_Last = rng.Find(What:="*", _
                            after:=rng.cells(1), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Row
        On Error GoTo 0

    Case 2:
        On Error Resume Next
        RDB_Last = rng.Find(What:="*", _
                            after:=rng.cells(1), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Column
        On Error GoTo 0

    Case 3:
        On Error Resume Next
        lrw = rng.Find(What:="*", _
                       after:=rng.cells(1), _
                       Lookat:=xlPart, _
                       LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                       SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                       SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                       MatchCase:=False).Row
        On Error GoTo 0

        On Error Resume Next
        lcol = rng.Find(What:="*", _
                        after:=rng.cells(1), _
                        Lookat:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Column
        On Error GoTo 0

        On Error Resume Next
        RDB_Last = rng.Parent.cells(lrw, lcol).Address(False, False)
        If Err.Number > 0 Then
            RDB_Last = rng.cells(1).Address(False, False)
            Err.Clear
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0

    End Select
End Function
```

Code is from this link.

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win008.htm